# Update App Registration Approles by Microsoft Graph API Patch method returns always Unable to read JSON request payload

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, powershell-2.0, azure-cli

On a App Registration I want to remove the App Roles by first disable the active ones and afterwards removing them.
I checked the commands by the developer tools what is executed and I come to the following request:

```
$graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications'+'/'+$apiAppReg.appId
$body = '{"appRoles":[{"description":"Applications can read","displayName":"Reader","id":"xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx","isEnabled":false,"value":"Read","allowedMemberTypes":["Application"]}]}
'

az rest --method PATCH --url $graphApiUrl --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '$body'
```

I tried this in all orders, but it seems that this is resulting in an error.

btw. the boby is copy from the request from the azure website

Comment: In the end the code was almost correct, the only problem is the quoting.
Apperently the az rest body will not accept double quotes....
So I had to add -replace '"','''' to the body...

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement using PowerShell. To Disable the App Role I have set `IsEnabled=$false` for each app role in my Application.

Below is the script that worked for me to disable the app role.

```
$App = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
$AppRoles = $app.AppRoles
for($I=0;$I -lt $AppRoles.Count;$I++)
{
    $app.AppRoles[$I].IsEnabled=$false
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $AppRoles
}
```

[image]

To Remove the app roles from the application I have used `$AppRoles.Remove($AppRoles[$I])`. Below is the complete code that worked to delete the app roles from my Application.

```
for($I=0;$I -lt $AppRoles.Count;$I++)
{
    $AppRoles.Remove($AppRoles[$I])
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $AppRoles
}
```

Below is the complete working code

```
Connect-AzureAD

$AppId = "<APPLICATION_ID>"
$ObjectId = "<OBJECT_ID>"

$App = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
$AppRoles = $app.AppRoles
for($I=0;$I -lt $AppRoles.Count;$I++)
{
    $app.AppRoles[$I].IsEnabled=$false
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $AppRoles
}

for($I=0;$I -lt $AppRoles.Count;$I++)
{
    $AppRoles.Remove($AppRoles[$I])
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -AppRoles $AppRoles
}
```